# Running Cassandra 4.0 Coordinator with 4.1 Cassandra storage nodes

Tags: cassandra

I have some questions around running Cassandra 4.1 storage nodes with dedicated coordinator-only Cassandra 4.0 nodes. I understand that some 4.1 specific features won't be available with this topology.

1. I can see different Schema Version Hash in between the Coordinator and Storage nodes, which is as expected. So far in my testing, I haven't seen any issues making schema changes and nodes are able to reach schema agreement. As far as I understand Schema Change restrictions are only in between major versions. Is there anything that I am missing here?
2. I can verify the streaming operations working fine with this topology like repairs and scaling of cluster (adding more nodes). Are there any other potential issues that I am not thinking?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more context into what you mean by coordinator/storage nodes? In Cassandra all nodes are responsible for coordinating requests and storing data.

Comment: Also, be aware of possible differences in sstables https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-4.1-New-SSTable-Identifiers.html